# Prolog- what causes the out of local stack error in this case?

Tags: prolog

I have a very simple program where a relation is defined between an AVL tree and a list of elements. I get correct results but after some semicolons I will receive an out of memory error, even for small inputs.

The code is not perfect as I am just trying at first to get to know the language, so it is not efficient but my question is where is the infinite loop or something similar hiding.

Only the last rule causes this problem, I tested the previous ones earlier and they worked fine.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% Stuff

max(X,Y,X):- X#>=Y.
max(X,Y,Y):- Y#>X.

sub(X,Y,Z):- Z is X-Y.

append([],Ys,Ys).
append([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):-append(Xs,Ys,Zs).

% Checking "tree-ness" of a term
% is_tree(Tree)

is_tree(tree(_,Left,Right)) :-
   Left=nil, Right=nil;
   Left=nil, is_tree(Right);
   Right=nil, is_tree(Left);
   is_tree(Left), is_tree(Right).

% Computing tree height
% tree_height(Tree, Height)

tree_height(nil,0).
tree_height(tree(_,L,R),H) :-
   tree_height(L,H1),
   tree_height(R,H2),
   H1#>=H2,
   H is H1+1.
tree_height(tree(_,L,R),H) :-
   tree_height(L,H1),
   tree_height(R,H2),
   H2#>H1,
   H is H2+1.

% Checking "AVL tree-ness" of a term
% is_avl_tree(Tree, Height)

is_avl_tree_help(nil,0).
is_avl_tree_help(tree(_,L,R),H) :-
    is_avl_tree_help(L,H1),
    is_avl_tree_help(R,H2),
    sub(H1,H2,D),
    D in -1 .. 1,
    max(H1,H2,H3),
    H is H3+1.    

is_avl_tree(Tree,H) :-
    is_tree(Tree),
    is_avl_tree_help(Tree,H).

% Define relation between a Tree and a List

tree_elements_help(nil,[]).
tree_elements_help(tree(X,Le,Ri),L) :-
    tree_elements_help(Le,L1),
    tree_elements_help(Ri,L2),
    append(L1,[X|L2],L).

tree_elements(Tree,L) :- 
    is_tree(Tree),
    tree_elements_help(Tree,L).

avl_tree_planter(Tree,L) :-
    is_avl_tree(Tree,H),
    tree_elements(Tree,L2),
    permutation(L2,L).
```

Comment: Nice. You miss `is_tree(nil)`. Points: `append/3` should already exist in some library and `is` can be replaced by using #=. `tree_height` should need just two clauses. There should be no need to do `is_tree(Tree)` in `is_avl_tree/2` (especially on every tree node examined!), you can get it for free "en passant".

Comment: @David: The lack of `is_tree(nil)` cannot cause non-termination.

Comment: @false I agree, but you can't have an empty tree then.

Comment: OP's question was "what causes the out of local stack error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that predicates like `tree_elements/2` and `avl_tree_planter/2` are not reversible. I assume you noticed the issue after calling `avl_tree_planter/2` with its first argument uninstantiated. For example, the following queries do not terminate:

```
?- tree_elements(Tree,[]).
?- avl_tree_planter(Tree,[]).
```

I will focus on the simpler case of writing a reversible predicate `inorder/2` that generates every binary tree having a given inorder traversal. The following implementation does not terminate when its first argument is uninstantiated:

```
inorder(leaf,[]).
inorder(node(X,L,R),L3) :-
    inorder(L,L1),
    inorder(R,L2),
    append(L1,[X|L2],L3).
```

If you trace the query `?- inorder(Tree,[])` you will find that the first recursive call to `inorder/2` causes the problem. In order to prove `inorder(Tree,[])` it is necessary to prove infinitely many goals of the form `inorder(X,[])`. In general, the first recursive call to `inorder/2` prevents the construction of the left subtree. This is analogous to the problem of left recursion in parsing.

Here is one solution. We introduce two arguments that track the state of the traversal. The first argument represents the input state and tracks the unprocessed elements. The second represents the output state and tracks the remaining elements. Their [difference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Difference_Lists) corresponds to the elements processed during a recursive call. It follows that `inorder(Tree,List)` should succeed with input state `List` and output state `[]`. Here is one possible implementation:

```
inorder(Tree,List) :-
    inorder(Tree,List,List,[]).

inorder(leaf,[],State,State).
inorder(node(X,L,R),List,[_|State1],State3) :-
    inorder(L,Left,State1,State2),
    inorder(R,Right,State2,State3),
    append(Left,[X|Right],List).
```

For example:

```
?- inorder(leaf,List).
List = [].

?- inorder(node(1,leaf,leaf),List).
List = [1].

?- inorder(node(1,node(2,leaf,leaf),leaf),List).
List = [2, 1].

?- findall(Tree,inorder(Tree,[]),Trees).
Trees = [leaf].

?- findall(Tree,inorder(Tree,[1]),Trees).
Trees = [node(1, leaf, leaf)].

?- findall(Tree,inorder(Tree,[1,2]),Trees).
Trees = [node(1, leaf, node(2, leaf, leaf)), node(2, node(1, leaf, leaf), leaf)].
```

If this implementation reminds you of parsing, that's because it implements roughly the same functionality as the following [definite clause grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) (DCG). The following code and a discussion of the relationship between nontermination and left recursion can be found at Markus Triska's [DCG tutorial](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg), which I suggest reading. Using DCG's for list processing is considered idiomatic Prolog.

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

inorder(Tree,List) :-
    phrase(inorder(Tree,List,_),List).

inorder(leaf,S,S) -->
    [].
inorder(node(X,L,R),[_|S1],S3) -->
    inorder(L,S1,S2),
    [X],
    inorder(R,S2,S3).
```

How to solve your original problem? In order to adapt these techniques to the setting of AVL trees, you need to place additional restrictions on which trees are generated (i.e., only succeed with binary search trees satisfying the AVL property). This should not be difficult. I hope you found this explanation helpful.

Comment: I regret learning about algorithms via Dijkstra's imperative pseudo-code with a difficult-to-understand proof grafted from mathematics (rambling full FOL zombified with time variables) on the side. That was not clean. This is clean.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer The credit for the trick is owed to Markus Triska's discussion of the same problem in the tutorial I linked.

Comment: There is something I still don't get fundamentally in inorder/2 though. Grr. Also: 1) In this case we don't care what's in the "unprocessed" state, we just dump the head of the list into an anonymous variable 2) We don't modify the "processed" state at all? It's not needed, but we should?

Comment: 3) I feel  processed/unprocessed business is not about the problem at hand, but really about controlling the Prolog engine's behaviour, it's at the same level as a "!", only it looks like standard code 4) I feel it is best described as information flowing through the temporally ordered series of procedure calls, from "unprocessed" down the call tree to "processed" up the call tree and "bouncing" at the leafs of the call tree 5) If you move the `append` in `inorder` to before the recursive `inorder` calls, determining the `List` given a `Tree` goes into +oo.